# Delete file obj c

Tags: objective-c, nsfilemanager

I am creating files with the following code

```
NSString *docPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *filename = @"xyz123.data";
docPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docPath, filename];

NSError *error = nil;
[data writeToFile:docPath options:0 error:&error];
```

To delete files I use the following

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSError *error = nil;

NSString *path = @"xyz123.data";
//NSString *path = @"Documents/xyz123.data";
[manager path error:&error];
```

But neither the first nor the second path seem to work, I always get the error "no such file or directory".

Comment: show declaration of data

Comment: NSData *fullData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:tuple[1]]; It is then passed to my create method

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You used `NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent` in the file creation, but not in either path when you try to delete the file.  Try:

```
[manager removeItemAtPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/xyz123.data"] error:&error]
```

Answer (score 24):

Try this:

```
NSString *docPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *filePath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"xyz123.data"];
NSError *error = nil;
[data writeToFile:filePath options:0 error:&error];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
```