# Updating Plist file via download iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I've got a quiz app on the Apple app store. The questions are stored in a Plist file. What I'm looking to do is find a way to update the Plist file via downloading a new version and not having to submit an update every time I have new questions to add

Does anyone know of a decent tutorial which may help me?

Many thanks.

Comment: [downloadingFile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101179/download-plist-from-server)___ [deletingFile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505529/delete-file-obj-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about tutorials, but the steps to achieve what you describe are pretty simple:

1. Create a url request to your remote data
2. Parse the returned data
3. Write the parsed data to a new local plist

Eg:

```
// Create a NSURL to your data
NSString *dataPath = @"www.mydata.com/path";
NSURL *dataURL = [NSURL URLWithString:dataPath];

// Create an asycnhronous request along with a block to be executed when complete
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:dataURL]
                                   queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {
     if (error) {
         NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
         // Handle the request error
     }
     else {
         // We have some data, now we need to serialize it so that it's usable
         NSError *serializationError;
         NSDictionary *serializedDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&serializationError];
         if (serializationError) {
             NSLog(@"%@", serializationError.localizedDescription);
             // Handle the serialization error
         }
         else {
             // We have a serialized NSDictionary, now we just want to write it
             // First we create the path to write it to, eg. uers documents directory
             NSURL *documentsDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
             // Then write it
             BOOL success = [serializedDictionary writeToFile:documentsDirectory.path atomically:YES];
             if (!success) {
                 NSLog(@"Error writing file");
             }
         }
     }
 }];
```

Note: You may want to think about storing your data in a remote database like [Parse](https://www.parse.com). This way you can query for new questions and only download those so you're not using unnecessary bandwidth. You may also want to consider using `Core Data` to maintain your local data rather than writing it to a plist. The main advantage being that you don't have to serialise the entire plist into memory to use it - you can just query for the particular questions you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already used Parse for push notifications but had no idea it could do this too. The only problem about moving away from the Plist would be the 3000 questions that are already on it and migrating it.

Comment: A common practice for data driven applications is to use the plist as the starting point and feed it into `Core Data`. You could then incorporate a periodical server query to see if there's anything new, and if so, update `Core Data` with the new remote data

Comment: So an example flow might be:
- On launch check if `Core Data` has been populated (eg. run a query with no predicate)
- If it returns 0 objects, then this is the first launch, so serialise your plist, then iterate over every question, inserting a new `NSManagedObject` for each one
- Otherwise, you've already done this - `Core Data` is good to go
- Query parse for all questions that were updated after you last updated (keep track of this via an `NSDate` stored in `NSUserDefaults`)
- If there are any results, then either create new `NSManagedObjects` for them or update current ones